# Can I use V4L2 to read a h264 video file input stream instead of a camera stream?

Tags: video-encoding

I'm trying to find a small clear example of using V4L2 in c or c++ for how to read directly from a h264 video file on disk.

Alternatively how I can pass a parsed full frame h264 chunk/packet to a open V4L2 decode device.

Does anyone know if this can be done at all or if there are any working examples around?

(Btw I know of gstreamer, ffmpeg/avcodec but I'm trying to figure this out for v4l2)

CheerS!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is the v4l2loopback device, which basically gives you a virtual `/dev/videoX` device that shows up as a camera for the tools you may be using.

To use it, you need to install the `v4l2loopback-dkms`-package of your distro, and load the module with `modprobe v4l2loopback`

To stream a video to this virtual camera, run:
`ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video0`, where `input.mp4` is your input video file and `/dev/video0` corresponds to the virtual device created by v4l2loopback (check which one is the correct one with `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip I should have mentioned maybe that I had tried that. It doesn't seem to be as easy as swapping my camera input video0 to the loopback though as when I tried to do that in my source I got an error with VIDIOC_EXPBUF and the loopback author says in a git issue that is not supported.

But obvs people have got it to work on command line so maybe I'll have to look at it again.

It does seem a bit like a hacky way though and I'm surprised there's no obvious 'official' way.

Comment: @RedMarsBlueMoon: What program versions are you using? For me, this worked perfectly under `Linux 5.10.23-1-MANJARO` with `v4l2loopback-dkms 0.12.5-1` and `ffmpeg 2:4.3.2-2`. Also, can you check if you used the right `dev/videoX`-device? If you have a webcam connected, X may be 2 or higher, check the `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`-output.

Comment: I was writing my own C program and was trying to convert my MIPI camera streamer to a video file streamer. I was doing video0 -> dmabuf -> OpenGL texture all without memory copy.    
But great to hear that you have made something work I will definitely pursue more testing of the loopback methods then!    
Yes I did notice that the device I got was +1 of the previous ones so I got a /dev/video2 loopback.